# Reusable type annotation for function declaration in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
type Func = (foo:string) => void

// function expression
const myFunctionExpression:Func = function(foo) {
  console.log(foo)
}
```

In the Typescript snippet above, I am using type alias to annotate the variable in a function expression.

The type alias:

```
type Func = (foo:string) => void
```

is reusable in another function expression to reduce repetition.

My question is: Is there a way to reuse this type alias to annotate a function declaration ?

```
// function declaration
function myFunctionDeclaration(foo:string):void {
  console.log(foo)
}
```

After some search online, I cannot seem to find such syntax, what am I missing?

Thanks

**update:**

At the time of this writing there is a ticket on github requesting for this feature: [Suggestion: Type annotations and interfaces for function declarations #22063](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) (thanks to comment from  @jcalz)

Comment: @jcalz Although this question lead to same answer, it is not a duplicate. 

This question inquired about the annotation syntax for a *function declaration* while the duplicated question in reference inquired about syntax for annotating *class method*. 

This question express the curiosity on the fact that while there is a syntax for annotating a *function expression*; no syntax is available to annotate a *function declaration*.  In JS & its varient, function declaration, expression and method are similar but they are not the same.

Comment: I don't claim to be the arbiter of StackOverflow etiquette, but I think the marking as a duplicate is [reasonable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406).  Since this question has apparently been answered to your satisfaction, the primary purpose of this question is now to help future searchers with your problem.  I expect they will benefit from the prominent link to the other question and answer.  Or at least I don't see how it hinders them.

Comment: For those reviewing the request to re-open, the answers linked do not answer this question. I am able to answer this question correctly once re-opened –

Comment: @apollo answer added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the typescript utility types available from version 3.1 to achieve this.

1. `Parameters<Type>` :
   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype
2. `ReturnType<Type>` : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

---

*Example fitting the question:*

[Typescript Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLxQBQDMD2OBcAzsAE4CWCA5gJRoB8UAbjmQCYCwAUFwPQ9RZESYGRwIoEAB5gSEQoVEIuSMcSgBbEPGQixAUWmz5i-NpTpBOxdjy0A3lyhQVCQjgA2EAHTuclGzjUXAC%20vPyWwopQrBBI7gCGJPG6SpwRKRpaQikAIrEJSSkYXiUA2rg4ALr4UAAKifHqEMAQJIQAPGZ01DUASs1wJAgAKuAQnUIMDpxOLm6ePn4BQZzBQA)

```
type Func = (foo:string) => void

// function expression
const myFunctionExpression:Func = function(foo) {
  console.log(foo)
}
// function declaration
function myFunctionDeclaration(...[foo]: Parameters<Func>): ReturnType<Func> {
  console.log(foo)
}
```

Comment: Although the spread in the formal parameter is somewhat awkward to read, it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

At time of writing (TypeScript 3.4), there is not a way to apply a type to a function declaration.